# Running .Net Framework application on xp without .Net installed

Tags: c#, .net, mono, static-linking, mkbundle

I’ve got an application written in .Net Framework 4.0, that I need to be able to run on Win xp sp3 without .Net installed.

I’ve found that using mono and mkbundle --static --deps, I can achieve what I need (if I understand it correctly). So I started with a simple “Hello world” app:

```
using System;

namespace Hello
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello world");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

But when I use:

```
mkbundle --static --deps Hello.exe -o Hello -L /usr/lib/mono/4.0-api
```

error occurs.

Edit: Thanks to gethomast I’ve succesfully build app for linux. I had to use:

```
mkbundle --fetch-target mono-6.0.0-ubuntu-18.04-x64
mkbundle --static --deps Hello.exe -o Hello --cross mono-6.0.0-ubuntu-18.04-x64 --i18n none
```

But I need to run my app on windows xp. 
Is there an option to download tools/runtime for windows xp?
Or maybe I need to use mono installed on xp to build app?
Or maybe I can use win 10 with older mono and VS installed?

Anyone had some experience on that subject? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

known issue at mono github, see https://github.com/mono/mono/issues/16829

Comment: Thanks, now it works on linux. 
Unfortunately I need to run it on windows. If I use --list-targets I cannot see any windows platform to choose. How can I build it for windows?